Reported Cosmos DB collection size unstable
I have observed a strange behavior with some (not all) Cosmos DB (NoSQL) collections. I read the collection size by retrieving the x-ms-resource-usage header from this response:
ContainerResponse response = await this.Container.ReadContainerAsync(new ContainerRequestOptions
{
    PopulateQuotaInfo = true
});

Even though the collection is stable (no writes), the returned value for collectionSize randomly oscillates between two or three different values every time I execute the code above, e.g.
collectionSize=359621
collectionSize=359429
collectionSize=359433
collectionSize=359433
collectionSize=359621
collectionSize=359433
collectionSize=359429

(The same small oscillation can be observed with documentsSize, but documentsCount is constant.)
Is that a bug? Is there a workaround?

I have seen this sort of quirk before. I've wondered whether this might be due to slight differences between the replicas that make up a physical partition and then just depend on the luck of the draw which replica per partition is contacted to get this value. Not sure if there might be processes like compaction or garbage deletion that can run independently on these?
